# Formal and correct syntax to sort a field from the joined table using Sequelize.js findAll

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two tables - `Customer` and `Orders` which are in one-to-many relationship. I'm querying both tables using [findAll()](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/models/#findall-search-for-multiple-elements-in-the-database) and trying to sort `Orders.orderDate` by descending. The following are all wrong and result query error.

#### Wrong Syntax (1)

```js
Customer.findAll({
    order: [["orderDate", "DESC"]],
    include: [Order]
}, {
    raw: true
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}); 
// Generated order by clause
// ORDER BY "Customer"."orderDate" DESC;
```

#### Wrong Syntax (2)

```js
Customer.findAll({
    order: [["Orders.orderDate", "DESC"]],
    include: [Order]
}, {
    raw: true
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}); 
// Generated order by clause
// ORDER BY "Customer"."Orders"."orderDate" DESC;
```

#### Wrong Syntax (3)

```js
Customer.findAll({
    order: ["Orders.orderDate", "DESC"],
    include: [Order]
}, {
    raw: true
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
// Generated order by clause
// ORDER BY "Orders"."orderDate", "DESC";
```

#### Wrong Syntax (4)

```js
Customer.findAll({
    order: ["Orders.orderDate DESC"],
    include: [Order]
}, {
    raw: true
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
// Generated order by clause
// ORDER BY "Orders"."orderDate DESC";
```

The following is the one I got it working:

```js
Customer.findAll({
    order: '"Orders"."orderDate" DESC',
    include: [Order]
}, {
    raw: true
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
// Generated order by clause
// ORDER BY "Orders"."orderDate" DESC;
```

However, I suspect that it could not be a formal and correct one as I have to add the double quotes manually. Quotes around table names an field names are automatically added in the above wrong syntax examples.

I'm using Sequelize 2.0.0-rc3 with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a correct usage. The model object has to be given in the array of the `order` option.

```js
Customer.findAll({
    order: [[ Order, "orderdate", "DESC" ]],
    include: [Order]
}, {
    raw: true
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
// Generated order by clause
// ORDER BY "Orders"."orderDate" DESC;
```